# Grep: Combining -o and -v flags does not work

Tags: grep

I want to combine the `-o` and `-v` flag of grep. But i do not get any output.
I have the file:

```
foo
bar
foobar
```

I call: `grep -vo foo ./file`

What i expect:

```
bar
bar
```

or

```
bar
bar
```

But i get no output.

From the man page of grep:

```
   -o, --only-matching
          Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.
...
   -v, --invert-match
          Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
```

When i only use one flag, the behavior is as i expect it. But how to make grep work with both flags work at the same time?
I use grep (GNU grep) 3.3 on Debian AMD64.

Answer (score 1):

What you are telling `grep` is:

> - Print only `foo` for each line that has it, and
> - Print lines that don't have a `foo`

What you meant to tell grep was:

> - Print lines that don't match `foo`, or the parts of lines that don't include a `foo`

That can be reduced to:

> - Print every line, but remove `foo` from them

I think `sed` is the perfect tool to do this:

```
$ sed 's/foo//g' ./file

bar
bar
```

This says: *for each line, substitute `foo` with nothing globally*.  By *globally* it means every instance in the line.

If you also want to delete empty lines:

```
$ sed -e 's/foo//g' -e '/^$/d' ./file
bar
bar
```

This says:

- *substitute `foo` with nothing globally*, then
- *for each empty line, delete it*